# Omit elements in array based on the first word

Tags: java, parsing

What I'm looking to do here is process a log file, in my case it's squid's [access.log](http://pastebin.com/a256rGjD). I want to have my program take a look at the first 'word' in the file, which is the time in Unix format of when the URL was accessed. In other parts of the program, I designed a time class, which gets the time the program was last run in Unix time, and I want to compare this time to the first word in the file, which happens to be a Unix time.

My initial thinking on how to do this is that I process the file, store it in array, then based on the first word in the file, omit the lines by removing it from the array that the processed file is in, and put it in another array

Here's what I've got so far. I'm pretty sure that I'm close, but this is the first time that I've done file processing, so I don't exactly know what I'm doing here.

```
    private void readFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    String[] lines = new String[getLineCount(file)];
    Long unixTime = time.getUnixLastRun();


    String[] removedTime = new String[getLineCount(file)];


    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        int i = 0;
        for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; i++) {
            lines[i] = line;

        }   
   }

    for(String arr: lines){
        System.out.println(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to compare time from each and every line? Lets say you have 100 lines in your file, will all those 100 lines have time as the first word of line? I am just a bit confused.

Comment: @Sneh Yeah. That's exactly right. Each line in the log starts off the same way--with a Unix time. I want to compare the UNIX time that's in the log and omit old entries. The program knows what time it was run last, In unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void readFile(File file) {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> firstWord = new ArrayList<String>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String sCurrentLine;
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // Adds the entire first line
            lines.add(sCurrentLine);
            // Adds the first word
            firstWord.add(sCurrentLine.split(" ")[0]);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you want you can use your arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
  private void readFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String[] lines = new String[getLineCount(file)];
        Long unixTime = time.getUnixLastRun();

        String[] removedTime = new String[getLineCount(file)];

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            int i = 0;
            for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; i++) {
                lines[i] = line;
            }
        }

        ArrayList<String> logsToBeUsed = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String arr : lines) {
             //Gets the first word from the line and compares it with the current unix time, if it is >= unix time
            //then we add it to the list of Strings to be used
            try{
                if(Long.parseLong(getFirstWord(arr)) >= unixTime){
                    logsToBeUsed.add(arr);
                }
            }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
                //Means the first word was not a float, do something here
            }
        }
    }

    private String getFirstWord(String text) {
        if (text.indexOf(' ') > -1) { 
            return text.substring(0, text.indexOf(' ')); 
        } else {
            return text; 
        }
    }
```

This is the answer according to the code you posted. This can be done more efficiently as you can use an `ArrayList` to store the lines from the file rather than first reading the line number `getLineCount(file)` as you open the file twice. And in the for loop you are declaring the `String` object again and again.